# Sorting date field by Day and Month in a MongoDB Query in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I wanted to sort the results of a query by a Date of Birth field, but while storing a garbage year value.
This is because, we used to allow birth year, but we do not require it anymore.

I am using Spring in Java, with MongoDB as the database.

The data should be sorted like this:

```
1. 2004-03-05        7. 2005-01-28
2. 2001-03-03        2. 2001-03-03
3. 2003-12-08        1. 2004-03-05
4. 2015-10-08   ->   6. 1999-07-16
5. 1999-09-24        5. 1999-09-24
6. 1999-07-16        4. 2015-10-08
7. 2005-01-28        3. 2003-12-08
```

This is how I am currently sorting the query.
I first sort by the specified field `sortingField`, and then by the `_id` of the object so that the data is always in the same order. In the case of my question, `sortingField = "dob"`

```
List<Sort.Order> sortList = new ArrayList<>();

sortList.add(
    new Sort.Order(
        sortDirection.compareToIgnoreCase("d") == 0
                ? Sort.Direction.DESC
                : Sort.Direction.ASC,
        sortingField));

sortList.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id"));

query.with(Sort.by(sortList));
```

I then get the result using `List<Customer> = mongoTemplate.find(query, Customer.class);`

Is this possible?

Comment: *we used to allow birth year, but we do not require it anymore* … Does that mean you are only interested in the day/date of someones birthday without being interested in the actual age?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: I hope the last date of the desired result is a typo and should be `"2003-12-08"`…

Answer (score 1):

#### For sorting in Java…

You can write your own `Comparator`…

##### `Comparator<LocalDate>`

If you write a custom `Comparator<LocalDate>`, you can simply sort by a *sub-unit* or *part* of the `LocalDate`:
The `MonthDay`, which only holds information about the day-of-month and the month-of-year and it is already implementing `Comparable<MonthDay>` exactly as desired.

##### Code example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create the list of Strings to be sorted
    List<String> birthdayStrings = List.of(
                "2004-03-05",
                "2001-03-03",
                "2003-12-08",
                "2015-10-08",
                "1999-09-24",
                "1999-07-16",
                "2005-01-28"
            );
    // map this list to a sortable one by parsing the Strings to LocalDates
    List<LocalDate> birthdays = birthdayStrings.stream()
                                               .map(LocalDate::parse)
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // print the list once
    birthdays.forEach(System.out::println);
    // print some separator in order to visually separate the unsorted from the sorted result
    System.out.println("—".repeat(12));
    // define a comparator for LocalDates that sorts by month-of-year first, then by day-of-month
    Comparator<LocalDate> monthDayComp = new Comparator<LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(LocalDate o1, LocalDate o2) {
            // simply sort by (already comparable) part of the LocalDate: MonthDay
            return MonthDay.from(o1).compareTo(MonthDay.from(o2));
        }
    };
    // sort the list using the comparator
    birthdays.sort(monthDayComp);
    // print the sorted list
    birthdays.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

##### Output

```
2004-03-05
2001-03-03
2003-12-08
2015-10-08
1999-09-24
1999-07-16
2005-01-28
————————————
2005-01-28
2001-03-03
2004-03-05
1999-07-16
1999-09-24
2015-10-08
2003-12-08
```

Comment: Sorry, can this be done using a MongoDB query, as the title suggested?

Comment: Does that mean the java tag is totally unrelated here?

Comment: No, because I am using Spring in Java, so I would appreciate code in it's syntax

Comment: Well, can't you simply `group by` month-of-year and day-of-month in the query? How does your query look at the moment? That's not shown in your question…